# Is it possible to replace "who" with "whom" in the bold clause?

Tags: who-whom

> “ ‘Yet the account of one mourner genuinely touched me. In response to the inquiry of a man **who she may not have realized was a reporter**, she revealed that she had met Landry at a treatment facility, and that they had become friends.
>   (The Cuckoo’s Calling, by Robert Galbraith)

I am curious to know if **who** in the bold clause can be replaced by **whom**. I mean is it possible?

Comment: Short answer: No.  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly  Especially this answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/94/17956

Comment: Note that this case is neither simple nor cut and dried, because *who* is part of the object predicates of both the preposition *of* (it's a pronoun replacement for a man) and *realized* in the bold clause (which uses a complex grammatical structure). Answers which treat the bold portion as an independent clause and ignore the broader context or remainder of the sentence fail to address the question fully.

Answer (score 3):

No, you probably shouldn't replace the writer's ***"who"*** with ***"whom".***

Well, you physically can do that, but you probably shouldn't. For if you did, then the result would be considered by many (especially those who are teachers) to be ungrammatical.

The result would be considered to be ungrammatical (by them) because the relativized element or gap in the relative clause is functioning as a subject of an embedded content clause, and so, the relative pronoun is supposedly required (by *Dialect A* speakers) to be in nominative case: ***"who"***.

- In response to the inquiry of a **man**(i) [ **who**(i) she may not have realized *[ __(i) was a reporter]* ], . . .

Notice that the gap in the embedded content clause is functioning as the subject: *"**he** was a reporter."* And so, the expected relative pronoun is the nominative ***"who"***.

**ASIDE:** But be aware that there is a dialect within today's standard English whose speakers will usually use the accusative ***"whom"*** in these types of situations. *CGEL* labels that dialect as *Dialect B* in their discussion of it on pages 466-7, subsection "(e) Subject of an embedded content clause". *CGEL* considers this type of usage (Dialect B) to be "grammatical in some dialect(s) only", which they mark as **"%"**. One such example of Dialect B usage is: % *those **whom** he thought were guilty* -- page 466, [37.a]. *CGEL* says, on page 467:

> Dialect A, which selects nominative, has more speakers and is the one recommended by the manuals, but here is no reason to say that it is inherently better or more grammatically correct than Dialect B, which selects accusative: the dialects just have different rules.

NOTE: *CGEL* is the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL).

Comment: It is fine for me to see you talking about nominative case *who* +1

Comment: +1 Wise advice :)  [Although, of course, if it had to be marked for case, it would be accusative! (only joking, that's imo) -  it's just that we'll never know, because *who* isn't consistently marked for case!(imo again)]  :)

Comment: On the other hand some better advice might be to omit the pronoun altogether!!! :) [sorry, can't resist, it's one of my favourite personal observations]

Answer (score 0):

A trick (not rule) that works in *most of the cases* of whether 'who' or 'whom' to be used.

> Try using both - ***I*** and ***me*** for that sentence. If *I* fits, use *who* and if *me* fits, use *whom.* Likewise, if *he* fits, it's *who* and if *him* fits, it's *whom*.

Example of the 'first person' trick:

> ***_*** did Sarah give tickets to? ~ Sarah gave tickets to *me* <del>*(not I)*</del> So, the answer is *whom*.

In your example, we will use a 'third person' trick

> In response to the inquiry of a man who she may not have realized was a reporter... ~ She did not realize (that) *he* <del>*(not him)*</del> was a reporter.

So, no. It cannot be replaced with *whom*.

A hot tip from [GrammarGirl](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/who_whom.htm), worth mentioning here:

> Substitute *who* with the word *he*. If that part of the sentence still makes sense, then who is almost certainly correct.

Comment: **Who did Sarah give ticket to?** and **Whom did Sarah give ticket to** are both correct.

Comment: I disagree as the [GrammarMonster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/who_whom.htm) does! @Man_From_India

Comment: I understand it's the rule of the grammar that choose "whom" over "who" here. But still it's considered standard or even better stylistically to use "who" in **Who did Sarah give ticket to?**

Comment: This means you are okay with this sentence as well- *whoever this matter is concerned*

Comment: @snailplane again? Should I stop believing it?

Comment: @MaulikV I'm afraid almost every great writer in the English language disagrees with you. So does every published grammar by a reputable publisher. There's no evidence from the last two centuries that we can't use *who* for objects. Sorry, but that's  the actual way things are!

Comment: @MaulikV That site's not very good.